# How to get the title of a specific tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to get the title of a specific tab on chrome.

For example, when you play a song on spotify.com, the tab's title will change base on the current song.

So how can I get the tab's title and show it on the popup.html?

Comment: You can obtain the current page title through `document.title`.

Comment: This will give you all the info you need to get started... https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

Comment: also look at active tab permission since you might not need more

Comment: Also, please read **[ask]**.  This question is currently very low quality and will not attract good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you will need [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for tab and extension interaction

Something like this...

1. Create a content script file on your chrome extension
2. In that file, detect title changes using an eventListiner, and get the title value using `document.title`
3. Send a message with the updated title value attached, and send it to your extension app using [messge passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)
4. Receive the message on your popup.html